# Scapy Installation fail on Windows 7 64 bit Python 3.5

Tags: windows, python-3.x, scapy

I have been going crazy with this installation but nothing seems to work.

Python 3.5 is installed under : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32", so there is a space in between.

I installed scapy in 2 ways:

1. pip3 install scapy-python3
2. From the website http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy, I downloaded the link for Scapy-2.3.2 and then compiling it as python setup.py install (This was most likely for Python 2 because first, it failed on fname(chmod,0755) which I corrected to fname(chmod,0o755) but it expected some more arguments)

With each I tried running scapy terminal but to no-avail.
It returns the following error:

```
python: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Tried running the following code (want to ping google):

```
from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP

p=sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8")/ICMP())
if p:
    p.show()
```

But get the following error:

```
WARNING: Windows support for scapy3k is currently in testing.

Sniffing/sending/receiving packets should be working with WinPcap driver and
Powershell. Create issues at https://github.com/phaethon/scapy
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\rads x\Desktop\FIX\connectivity.py", line 13, in
<module>

from scapy.all import sr1,IP,ICMP
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py",
line 16, in <module>
from .arch import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-
packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
from .windows import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-
packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from scapy.arch import pcapdnet
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-
packages\scapy\arch\pcapdnet.py", line 32, in <module>
from .winpcapy import *
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-\
packages\scapy\arch\winpcapy.py", line 26, in <module>
_lib=CDLL('wpcap.dll')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 347, 
in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very old post.

For the record, official secdev/scapy now supports Python 3.
Feel free to have a look at their official github page:
https://github.com/secdev/scapy

Have a good week

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs scrapy is not supported on Windows with Python 3.x due to missing dependency (Twisted)

Source: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

Comment: jhole89 .. Thank you, but I was looking at another library called scapy